# C# Network encoding

Tags: c#, networking

I'm working on a networking application in C#, sending a lot of plain numbers across the network. I discovered the *IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder* and *IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder* methods, which are very useful, but they left me with a few questions:

1. **I know I need to encode and decode integers, what about unsigned ones?** I think yes, so at the moment I'm doing it by casting a pointer to the unsigned int into a pointer to an int, and then doing a network conversion for the int (since there is no method overload that takes unsigned ints)

   ```
   public static UInt64 HostToNetworkOrder(UInt64 i)
   {
       Int64 a = *((Int64*)&i);
       a = IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder(a);
       return *((UInt64*)&a);
   }

   public static UInt64 NetworkToHostOrder(UInt64 a)
   {
       Int64 i = *((Int64*)&a);
       i = IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder(i);
       return *((UInt64*)&i);
   }
   ```

   *2. **What about floating point numbers (single and double)**. I think no, however If I do need to should I do a similar method to the unsigned ints and cast a single pointer into a int pointer and convert like so?*

EDIT:: Jons answer doesn't answer the second half of the question (it doesn't really answer the first either!), I would appreciate someone answering part 2

Comment: y u do this?  y u no has wcf?

Comment: The system allows any implementation of networking (it's a library that relies on external networking), so I have to assume the external system won't do any network encoding for me.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you'd find it easier to use my `EndianBinaryReader` and `EndianBinaryWriter` in [MiscUtil](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/miscutil) - then you can decide the endianness yourself. Alternatively, for individual values, you can use `EndianBitConverter`.

Comment: Well, I'll have a look at how that works and probably write my own implementation. The original questions still stand though, do I need to encode singles and uints?

Comment: Martin, byte order is indepenent of sign, so yes.

Comment: I guessed uints need to be encoded, I assume you're implying yes for single/double too?

Comment: I almost never use fp so I wouldn't know firsthand.  However, it may well be that fp values are in a standard layout that's independent of byte order, so perhaps not.

Comment: Aye, that's the problem, I don't know and can't find any decent information on it :/

Comment: Unless Jon pipes up, I'd suggest doing a little experiment, rather than counting on reference material.

Comment: I believe it *does* depend on the endianness of the machine, and I can't remember offhand what EndianBitConverter does... but as Steven suggests, it's probably best to experiment.

Comment: The wikipedia link seems to suggest that floating point numbers are indeed endian specific, I guess I'd better go and find myself a little endian test machine and play with this.

Answer (score 0):

You'd better read several RFC documents to see how different TCP/IP protocols (application level, for example, HTTP/FTP/SNMP and so on).

This is generally speaking, a protocol specific question (both your questions), as your packet must encapsulate the integers or floating point number in a protocol defined format.

For SNMP, this is a conversion that changing an integer/float number to a few bytes and changing it back. ASN.1 is used.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One

Comment: This is for a udp system, so the protocol is largely self defined. Basically I send an array of bytes to the other end, using some arbitrary networking system. Then I have to decode those bytes.

Comment: The question is mostly if endianness effects floats in the same way it effects integers